# Mixing concurrently and cross-env in a package.json script

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, package.json, npm-scripts

Building a monorepo template, I'm facing an issue in the scripts of my `package.json`. I'm trying to make my scripts compatible with `npm` alternatives like `yarn` or `pnpm`. So I tried to use a [`config` object](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#config) to specify the wanted CLI:

```json
{
  "config": {
    "cli": "npm"
  }
}
```

Then I was able to access the value through the environment variable `npm_package_config_cli`. Since the usage of environment variables has different syntaxes between unix systems and windows, I used [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env). This worked well for most of my scripts, for example:

```json
"dev-front": "cross-env-shell \"cd ./frontend && $npm_package_config_cli run dev\"",
```

Here you can see the usage of `cross-env-shell` to execute the command between quotes:

```bash
cd ./frontend && $npm_package_config_cli run dev
```

With `$npm_package_config_cli` being resolved by `cross-env` according to the OS.

My `package.json` purpose is to drive the scripts in `frontend` and `backend` folders of my monorepo template. So I'm using [`concurrently`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) to keep track of the different outputs. My issue is when using `cross-env-shell` along with `concurrently`. I tried to call `cross-env-shell` "inside" `concurrently` and vice-versa, with single and/or double quotes, but `$npm_package_config_cli` is not resolved on windows.

A minimal `package.json` with the failing `dev` script (`dev-front` and `dev-back` are working):

```json
{
  "config": {
    "cli": "npm"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "concurrently -n front,back -c green,yellow -t 'HH:mm:ss' -p '{name} {time}' 'cross-env-shell \"cd ./frontend && $npm_package_config_cli run dev\"' 'cross-env-shell \"cd ./backend && $npm_package_config_cli run dev\"'"
    "dev-front": "cross-env-shell \"cd ./frontend && $npm_package_config_cli run dev\"",
    "dev-back": "cross-env-shell \"cd ./backend && $npm_package_config_cli run dev\""
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^7.6.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3"
  }
}
```

Any hint on the valid syntax? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying harder, the following combination worked with `concurrently` wildcards:

```json
{
  "config": {
    "cli": "npm"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env-shell 'concurrently -c green,yellow -t \"HH:mm:ss\" -p \"{name} {time}\" \"$npm_package_config_cli:dev-*\"'",
    "dev-front": "cross-env-shell \"cd ./frontend && $npm_package_config_cli run dev\"",
    "dev-back": "cross-env-shell \"cd ./backend && $npm_package_config_cli run dev\""
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^7.6.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3"
  }
}
```